# How to get the Evaluation Metrics using pyspark and jupyter?

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, metrics, evaluation

I am new in machine learning and in python. I am working on task using Logistic Regression. while I am trying to find out how to get the Evaluation Metrics using PySpark and Jupiter notebook, I get the following error.

```
from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import MulticlassMetrics
# Compute raw scores on the test set
predictionAndLabels = test.rdd.map(lambda lp: (float(lr_model.predict(lp.features)), lp.label))
metrics = MulticlassMetrics(predictionAndLabels)
```

The error

```
PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o123.__getstate__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Hi @Amer, welcome to stackoverflow! Is your question about how to correct the error you are getting?